# How to select all mesh regions in ParaView OpenFOAM case using python scripting?

Tags: python, paraview, openfoam

Loading an OpenFOAM case in ParaView using python is straight forward with:

```
ofReader = OpenFOAMReader(FileName='<some OpenFOAM case directory>')
```

However, by default only the `internalMesh` mesh region is selected in the reader object.

Using the trace method of ParaView is not of any help, since the `MeshRegion` property of the `OpenFOAMReader` object is simply set to the values of the mesh regions I select via mouse input:

```
ofReader.MeshRegions = ['internalField', 'patch1', 'patch2']
```

Since I do not know in advance what the mesh region names are I cannot produce such a line in my python ParaView script.

How is it possible to select and load all mesh regions of an OpenFOAM case in ParaView using a python script and only ParaView Python API functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a SelectAll() function on ArrayListPropery python class.

```
ofReader = OpenFOAMReader(FileName='<some OpenFOAM case directory>')
ofReader.MeshRegions.SelectAll()
Show(ofReader)
Render()
```

If you need to know the names though, this is also possible :

```
ofReader.GetProperty("PatchArrayInfo")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The answer above is working! Do you know if this is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Right here : https://www.paraview.org/ParaView/Doc/Nightly/www/py-doc/paraview.servermanager.html?highlight=selectall#paraview.servermanager.ArrayListProperty.SelectAll